# Encontrar Ids dentro de una lista según otra condición en LINQ

Tags: .net, linq

Tengo una lista de gastos de la cual quiero mirar 2 condiciones:

- Que **TODOS** tengan costes asignados (`AllocatedCosts`)
- Que si **ALGUNO** tiene un ticket adjunto me compruebe que este tiene un proveedor (`ProviderText`)

Es aquí en la segunda condición anidada donde tengo dificultades. He intentado:

```
IEnumerable<Spending> spendings;

if( (spendings.Any(s => s.AttachmentId > 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.ProviderText) )) && 
(spendings.All(s => s.AllocatedCosts) ){
  isProcesable = true;
}
else isProcesable = false;
```

Quiero que me compruebe si existe `ProviderText` solamente cuando se de la primera condición: `AttachmentId > 0`

---

Esta es el modelo de la clase `Spending`

```
   public class Spending {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string ProviderId { get; set; }
    public string ProviderText { get; set; }
    public int? AttachmentId { get; set; }
    public string AttachmentPath { get; set; }
    public string AttachmentName { get; set; }
    public bool AllocatedCosts { get; set; }
    // ....
   }
```

Comment: al tu decir que TODOS tengan costes asignados quieres decir que si uno no tiene coste se levante una exeption?

Comment: No. Ese `if`se comprueba que se cumplan las condiciones indicadas y da valor a un booleano. Edito el código para tratar de reflejarlo con más claridad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si entiendo exactamente tus requerimientos, pero lo que yo haría primero seleccionar los registros con `AttachmentId>0` y luego le aplicaría el `Any`,algo asi como:

```
if ((spendings.Where(x=>x.AttachmentId>0)
             .Any(y => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(y.ProviderText))) 
                   && (spendings.All(z => z.AllocatedCosts)))
```

Comment: Entiendo, me faltaba anidar el `Any` dentro del `Where`. Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

No tengo mucho conocimiento en LINQ, pero buscando como funcionan estas consultas anidadas, llegue a hacer esto. Se hace practicamente lo mismo que en tu consulta, salvo que ocupo la sentencia `Where` dentro de tu lista, para que asi me traiga los valores cumpliendo tus condiciones.

```
var result = tucontext.Tabla.Where(s => (s.AttachmentId > 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.ProviderText)) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.AllocatedCosts))
if (!result.Any()) 
{
    isProcesable = false;
}else 
{
    isProcesable = true;
}
```